# Using FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE, gives Not Responding error

Tags: android, android-windowmanager, android-layoutparams, android-window

Is there any way to remove that error?

I am using FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE in my activity, but when I touch the screen it appear not responding error...

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams params = getWindow().getAttributes(); 
params.flags |= LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE;
params.screenBrightness = (float) 0.0039999; 
getWindow().setAttributes(params);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you mean by "that error" and "not responding error" is the [Activity Not Responding](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/responsiveness.html#anr) error or **ANR**. At any rate, Dianne Hackborn, an Android Framework engineer, [address this exact problem on a Google Groups page here.](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-developers/DC2Jiiv33MU/7hlRGS4qkWoJ)

Answer (score 0):

I worked around this issue by creating a transparent view that overlays the entire window and captures onClick events. That way the app is "responsive" and no ANR is triggered, but the user can't actually click any buttons on the screen.